# JVectorMap with Svg Arc

Tags: jvectormap

How can i convert the dimension of arc based on my coordinates,

i have written this code using svgpath.js library

```
   path1[l] = draw
   .path()
   .attr({ fill: "none", stroke: "" + coordsToColors[l] + "", "stroke-width": 1.5 })
   .M(coordsFrom[i].x, coordsFrom[i].y)
   .A(100, 50, 0, 0, 1, { x: coordsTo[l].x, y: coordsTo[l].y });
```

[image]

[image: Jvector Map with Svg Arc]